# VBA получение формы по имени

Tags: excel, vba

Есть функция, которая должна производить определённые действия на форме. Хотел прописать функцию как-то так:

```
Sub workOnForm(formName as String)
    Dim curForm as UserForm
    set curForm = UserForms(formName)
    ' ..... действия с формой
End Sub
```

Но получаю ошибку `Type mismatch`. Есть ли способ присвоить форму переменной по имени, за исключением перебора всех форм и проверки их имени на совпадение указанному?

Либо же проще в функцию передавать саму форму?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллекция UserForms, если верить встроенной справке, итерируется ТОЛЬКО по индексу:

> **Syntax**
>
> **UserForm**
>
> **UserForms[.Item]**(*index*)

Передавать саму форму, несомненно, проще. Но и итерация по VBA.Forms не такая уж и сложная штука.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myFormObg
For Each myFormObg In UserForms
    If myFormObg.Name = formName Then
        myFormObg.Show
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]